# Upload millions of images from tablet to server

Tags: sql-server, image, iis, media

I want to architect a system that will allow thousands of users to upload images from a tablet to a content management system. In one upload, each user can upload up to 12 images at a time and there could be up to 20,000 uploads per day. As the numbers  are <240,000 images per day, I've been wondering what is the best approach to avoid bottle necking during peak times.

I'm thinking along the lines of using a web server farm (IIS) to upload the images though HTTP POST. Where each image is less than 200kB and I could store the images on a file system. This would be 48GB per day and only 16TB per year.

Then I could store the image metadata in SQL Server DB along with other textual data.  At a later time, the users will want to recall the images and other (text) data from a DB to the tablet for further processing.

On a small scale, this is no problem ,but I'm interested in what everyone thinks is the best approach for uploading/retrieving such a large number of images/records per day?

Comment: there are services that you can leverage for this. building such system from scratch will take several months of your time and still will be way behind.

Comment: Hiya what services are available?

Comment: I would suggest Uploadcare but I'm biased :)

Answer (score 1):

> I've been wondering what is the best approach to avoid bottle necking during peak times.

Enough hardware. Period.

> I'm thinking along the lines of using a web server farm (IIS) to upload the images though 
>   HTTP POST.

No alternative to that that is worth mentioning.

> This would be 48GB per day and only 16TB per year.

Yes. Modern storage is just fantastic ;)

> Then I could store the image metadata in SQL Server DB along with other textual data.

Which makes this ia pretty smal ldatbase - which is good. At the end that means the problem runs down into the image storage, the database is not really that big.

> On a small scale, this is no problem ,but I'm interested in what everyone thinks is the 
>   best approach for uploading/retrieving such a large number of images/records per day?

I am not sure you are on a large scale yet. Problems will be around:

- Number of files. You need to split them into multiple folders and best have the concept of buckets in the database so you can split them into multiple buckets each being their own server(s) - good for long term maintenance.
- Backup / restore is a problem, but a lot less when you use (a) tapes and (b) buckets as said above - the chance of a full problem is tiny. ALso "3-4 copies on separate machines" may work well enough.

Except the bucket problem - i.e. yo can not put all those files into a simple folder, that iwll be seirously unwieldely - you are totally fine. This is not exactly super big. Keep the web level stateless so you can scale it, same on the storage backend, then use the database to tie it all together and make sure you do FREQUENT database backups (like all 15 minutes).

Comment: Yes the issue of storing millions files over multiple local servers is new territory to me. Is there any background theory that I can read up on to find the best approach?

Comment: Not that I know of. Basically it runs down to a lot of things taking longer. Depending on file system you also may run into hard limitations. But windows for example - NO problem with a million files in a folder, UNTIL you open the folder for some reason in explorer.... the UI is not really designed with a million files in a folder in mind ;) THat happens with many tools. You definitely need sharding here.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible way is upload from client directly to Amazon S3. It will scale and receive any amount of files thrown at it. After upload to S3 is complete, save a link to S3 object along with useful meta to your DB. In this setup you will avoid file upload bottleneck and only have to be able to save ~240,000 records per day to your DB which should not be a problem.

If you want to build service that adds a value and save some (huge amount actually) time on file uploads, consider using existing 3rd party solutions that are built to solve this particular issue. For example - [Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com) and some of its competitors.